# How to edit the BibTeX .bst FUNCTION {format.names}?

Tags: latex, bibtex

After trying several .bst files I am still mostly satisfied with the layout of the ChicagoReedWeb.bst file. However, I don't like the handling of entries by the same author, eg:

---

[image: Example of Chicago Style]

---

If have looked at the ChicagoReedWeb.bst file but only understand some of the basics.
So how can I edit the code of the ChicagoReedWeb.bst file in such a way that it will print the author's full reference instead of the "--------" ?

Comment: I'm always amazed at the number of people who hate the Chicago Style of the long dash for repeated authors.  I suppose that people who read only recent books and technical papers have never seen it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, this is *well* outside my previous experience with BibTeX, but looking at the file, I get the impression that the `name.or.dash` section is replacing the name with a dash if it's the same as the previous one. I suggest trying replacing this code:

```
FUNCTION {name.or.dash}
{ 's :=
   oldname empty$
     { s 'oldname := s }
     { s oldname =
         { "\rule[.6ex]{3em}{.05ex}"}
         { s 'oldname := s }
       if$
     }
   if$
}
```

with this:

```
FUNCTION {name.or.dash}
{
}
```

If my understanding of the syntax is correct, this should simply remove the comparison and optional change, and leave the name as you want it.

A slightly tidier approach might be to take out the calls to `name.or.dash` in the places which you don't want them. That will give you more flexibility about whether you want a dash in place of, for example, a repeated book name.

Comment: I'd leave the calls to name.or.dash in: it may be that at some point in the future you want to treat repeated bibitems differently.  Renaming them, for the sake of readability, to repeated.name would make sense.